# Gmail extension design requirements

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail

Are there specific design requirements when creating a gmail extension such as Boomerang or Rapportive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build a chrome extension to add panel to gmail windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718913/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension-to-add-panel-to-gmail-windows)