# What is the best way to use gmail api when developing chrome extensions for gmail?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

I have generated client_id from google developer console. Is it necessary to load a client library and call the api using keyword gapi as shown in the official site [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js)? Since, i can get the authentication token using chrome.identity namespace, can't i use this token to make simple XMLHttpRequest to gmail apis?

Comment: Yes, you can use the token to access the API through XMLHttpRequest's without having to download the Google API client library. You have the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/)

Comment: How can i set other query parameters as described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list).If i need to fetch only email messages sent by certain user, then i need to set 'q' parameter most probably. Will settings these query parameters in a query string of XMLHttpRequest will work?

Comment: Yes, it will work using the 'q' parameter or any of the other query parameters.

Comment: In addition to @Iván Nokonoko's comments, you may follow this [tutorial](http://developer.streak.com/2014/10/how-to-use-gmail-api-in-chrome-extension.html) on how to use the Gmail API in a Chrome extension. In this [sample](https://gist.github.com/omarstreak/7908035c91927abfef59), there is an included `background.js` file that already does the necessary work to authorize and load the Gmail client library. You simply need to replace the `clientID` with the one you have generated. Here's another SO post which might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174710.

Comment: When i used chrome.identity.getAuthToken, token is undefined and gives an error message 'Authorization page could not be loaded' after i select a user from consent screen. To make my extension id constant i have uploaded my extension to chrome web store (have not published yet). Then i generated a client_id from google developer console and included in my manifest file, provided necessary permissions. However i am not able to generate token. What am i missing? Is it necessary to publish the extension to make identity work?